# Getting Phone Number and Name from Contacts ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I am trying to get the phone number and name from my contacts listview. This is what I have so far:

```
ListView lv;
Cursor cursor1;
Context context;
String phoneNumberStr;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts_screen_x);

    context = this;

    cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor1);




    String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor1, from, to);

    setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int PhoneNumber = cursor1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            phoneNumberStr = cursor1.getString(PhoneNumber);
            Intent SendText = new Intent(context, SendText.class);
            SendText.putExtra("PhoneNumber", phoneNumberStr);
            startActivity(SendText);
        }
    });

    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}
```

This is to only get the number, but I would also like to get the name.

This is what the logcat says:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.example.luke.percentagegradecalculator.SendText.onCreate(SendText.java:28)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368) 
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284) 
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
>                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)

I used intent to go to another java class and layout and get the extras and set a textview to the PhoneNumberStr. I believe that the string is null. Please help me!

Comment: post the oncreate method and the class/activity variables...

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa I just did

Answer (score 0):

In android an [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and the [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class are 2 different things, this here is the error...

```
Intent SendText = new Intent(context, SendText.class);
```

you are constructing an intent object with the intent itself you already defined... that is not going to work...

you have to change that to

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, SendTextActivity.class);
```

where the `SendTextActivity.class` is a class that extends an [android Activity class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: That is wrong. Intent has two things that need to go in it: the context and the java class. I don't where you got the Activity idea from. I actually used the exact same code (different java class name and intent name) in another project that works fine. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: ummm take a look at this if you think am wrong:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: "Note: The reference to DisplayMessageActivity (Activity is another name for the java class) will raise an error if you’re using an IDE such as Android Studio because the class doesn’t exist yet. Ignore the error for now; you’ll create the class soon." @ΦXoce 웃 Пepeúpa